# PHP. Потеря контекста при call_user_func

Tags: php, context

При вызове метода класса через `call_user_func` из другого класса теряется контекст и невозможно получить свойства, методы исходного класса.

Логика такая:

```
Class1 {
    private $class2;
    private $object = ...;

    public function func() {
        $this->object->...
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->class2 = new Class2();
        $this->class2->metod('Class1::func', ...);
    }
}

Class2 {
    ...
    public function metod($func) {
        ...
        call_user_func($func, ...);
    }
}
```

В методе `func()` возникает ошибка `Using $this when not in object context`

Как правильно обратиться к свойствам и методам `Class1` при вызове `func()` данным способом? `Class2` менять нельзя (это MultiCurl, который отлично работает в других приложениях, внутри другого класса использую впервые. `call_user_func` вызывает обработчик результата `Curl`).

Comment: а что такое `func() {` ?  у вас код рабочий? вообще нет. почти весь

Comment: func() - метод Class1 (function опустил для простоты)

Comment: Не надо **опускать для простоты**. Приведите валидный код, с которым проблемы

Comment: Приводить весь код нет смысла. многоточие - параметры (неважная часть) Главный вопрос - как использовать $this при таком вызове?

Comment: @Дмитрий дело в том, что 1) вы, видимо, достаточно слабо разбираетесь в теме и шансы того, что "неважная часть" на самом деле "важная" - достаточно велики 2) псевдокод хорош только в случае обсуждения каких-то теоретических, не завязанных на язык вещей. Вопросы про конкретные проблемы в конкретных языках гораздо проще обсуждать видя реальный неработающий код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не сильно вдаваться в суть того, что в коде происходит, то....

`call_user_func` для вызова **НЕ СТАТИЧЕСКОГО** метода, принимает массив, где 1 элемент - объект, 2 - название метода.

В итоге код ниже

```
class Class1 {
    private $class2;
    private $object = 666;

    public function func() {
        echo $this->object;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->class2 = new Class2();
        $this->class2->metod([$this, 'func']);
    }
}

class Class2 {

    public function metod($func) {    
        call_user_func($func);
    }
}

$test = new Class1();
```

выведет

```
666
```

---

Для **статического** надо действовать по-другому, однако в статическом методе нельзя использовать `$this`.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Answer (score 1):

В том примере, который вы привели

1) `Class1::func` - это синтаксис вызов статического метода. Однако сам метод `func` объявлен как не статический

2) Каким образом `call_user_func` в методе `method` класса `Class2` вызовет метод несуществующего объекта?

3) В методе `func` идет отсылка с свойствам объекта `$this->object->...` класса `Class1`, каким образом `Class2` о них знает?

Какой можно сделать вывод? Такой - в целом ваш "псевдокод" это какой-то адъ, который не только не объясняет суть вопроса, а наоборот, все запутывает.